# Trouble with the proof of convergence of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(-2)^n}$

I tried using D'Alembert's Ratio on it and this is how far I got:

$\frac{(n+1)}{(-2)^{n+1}}\frac{(-2)^n}{n}=\frac{n+1}{(-2)\cdot n}=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n}$.

But I can't see the convergence from here. I mean, I see that it's smaller than let's say $0$, but is such an argumentation enough?

**Edit:** I just found another one which baffles me.

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!+n^n}$

I tried writing this in a different way and got: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\frac{n!}{n^n}}$.

Once again I tried using D'Alembert's Ratio on it. But it only got me to $\frac{1}{1+\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}\cdot (1+\frac{n!}{n^n})$. But that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Compare what you do with the actual test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test (and spot the differences!).

Comment: You *can't* apply d'Alembert's test (ratio test) on a **non-positive** series, as you tried here. Either you use absolute values or else you try something else.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n =\frac{n}{(-2)^n }$ hence $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=\frac{(n+1) 2^n}{n2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)\to\frac{1}{2} <1.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second one:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\color{red}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{{(n+1)!}+{(n+1)^{n+1}}}\frac{{n!}+{n^n}}{\color{red}{n^n}}=$$

$$=\frac{n!+n^n}{n!+(n+1)^n}\color{red}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e>1$$

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that the term as a whole also converges to $e$. Shouldn't $\frac{n!+n^n}{n!+(n+1)^n}$ before that converge to zero, meaning that the whole expression should also converge to zero?

Comment: @Konstantin Not really: that expression has the same factorial in denominator and numerator, and the difference of the other term ($\;n\;,\;\;n+1\;$) is minor, thus the limit is one.

Comment: Really? Didn't know that. I always thought that how ever small the difference between the denominator and nominator is, that as long the denominator is some what greater it would converge to zero.

Comment: @Konstantin  That cannot be true, since then we'd have $\;\frac n{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , which is absurd...

Answer (score 0):

If $\left|x\right|<1
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq0}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}
 $$ then if we take the derivative $$\sum_{n\geq1}nx^{n}=\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}
 $$ and so $$\sum_{n\geq1}n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}=-\frac{2}{9}.
 $$ For the second, using the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Stirling%27s_approximation), $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n}}{n!+n^{n}}\geq\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{e^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}+e^{n-1}}
 $$ and $\frac{e^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}+e^{n-1}}\rightarrow1
 $.